# Call method in ViewModel when a EventTrigger is raised in a View

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .net-3.5

I would like to call a method of a ViewModel when a EventTrigger is raised in a View.
I want to do something like that, but in **MVVM** in my xaml code :

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded +=new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(ViewLoaded);
    }

    private void ViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyViewModel)this.DataContext).BeginWork();
    }
}
```

My apps is build with WPF 3.5, and I can not use Blend SKD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a DependencyProperty of type `ICommand`, call it "BeginWorkCommand" for example. Create a new class next to your viewmodel, or use a [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) to directly use it in your viewmodel. And finally bind this viewmodel command to your created dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GalaSofts` `EventToCommand`from the MVVM Light Toolkit [here](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)

```
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <WPFActions:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Where LoadedCommand is a command implemented in your ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private readonly ICommand loadedCommand;

    public ICommand LoadedCommand { get { return loadedCommand; } }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        loadedCommand = new RelayCommand(myLoadedHandler);
    }

    //...
}
```

RelayCommand is part of the toolkit too.